# Testing user password update with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, sequel, roda

I have an API built with Roda + Sequel stack. Here is how my `User` model looks like:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# {User} is model responsible for storing {User} authentication informations like email and password.
#
# @!attribute id
#   @return [UUID] ID of the {User} in UUID format.
#
# @!attribute email
#   @return [String] Email of the {User}, it's stored in the PostgreSQL citext column.
#
# @!attribute password_hash
#   @return [String] {User} hashed password with bcrypt.
#
# @!attribute created_at
#   @return [DateTime] Time when {User} was created.
#
# @!attribute updated_at
#   @return [DateTime] Time when {User} was updated
class User < Sequel::Model
  # It returns instance BCrypt::Password based on value in password_hash column.
  #
  # @return [BCrypt::Password ] based on value in password_hash column.
  #
  # @example Get {User} password hash:
  #   User.new(password: 'test').password #=> "$2a$12$FktSw7HPYEUYSPBdmmsiXe26II6UV5gvyn2ECwOflTYHP94Hrm2mS"
  def password
    @password ||= BCrypt::Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  # It sets password_hash column with hashed user password.
  #
  # @return [String] user password hash.
  #
  # @example Set {User} password:
  #   User.new(password: 'test').password_hash #=> "$2a$12$FktSw7HPYEUYSPBdmmsiXe26II6UV5gvyn2ECwOflTYHP94Hrm2mS"
  def password=(new_password)
    @password = BCrypt::Password.create(new_password)

    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

and I have the following test:

```
describe 'update user password' do
  let(:params) { { password: 'new-password' } }

  before do
    put '/api/v1/update_password', params

    user.reload
  end

  it 'returns 200 HTTP status' do
    expect(response.status).to eq 200
  end
   
  This one is failing.
  it 'updates user password' do
    expect(user.password == 'new-password').to eq true
  end
  
  # This one is passing.
  it 'updates user password' do
    expect(BCrypt::Password.new(user.password_hash).is_password?('new-password')).to eq true
  end
end
```

This example is failing:

```
  it 'updates user password' do
    expect(user.password == 'new-password').to eq true
  end
```

but this one is passing:

```
 it 'updates user password' do
    expect(BCrypt::Password.new(user.password_hash).is_password?('new-password')).to eq true
  end
```

Could someone explain to me why my first example is failing?

Comment: [`is_password?`](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/fc652e5248a4132af2c5f5c0b61eeceff02f4316/lib/bcrypt/password.rb#L68) is an alias for `==` so both should pass. What do `user.password` and `BCrypt::Password.new(user.password_hash)` return? (from within your RSpec examples)

Comment: There is this sequel plugin https://github.com/mlen/sequel_secure_password. It hasn't been updated in a while but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite this one

```rb
it 'updates user password' do
  expect(user.password == 'new-password').to eq true
end
```

to this one

```rb
it 'updates user password' do
  expect(user.password).to eq(BCrypt::Password.create('new-password'))
end
```

Your ruby object `User` contains hashed version of that password

```
user.password
=> "$2a$12$FktSw7HPYEUYSPBdmmsiXe26II6UV5gvyn2ECwOflTYHP94Hrm2mS"
'$2a$12$FktSw7HPYEUYSPBdmmsiXe26II6UV5gvyn2ECwOflTYHP94Hrm2mS' == 'new-password'
=> false
```

and in order to compare them you have to bcrypt your 'new-password' and compare two hashes. You can easily crypt any string with bcrypt, but decrypt it will take much time (years). It is common before verifying password, encrypt your `input password` with the same algorithm that your database contains

Answer (score 1):

You're answering your question yourself: you're hashing the password before it's saved (in the password setter in `User.rb`:

```
  # It sets password_hash column with hashed user password.
  #
  # @return [String] user password hash.
  #
  # @example Set {User} password:
  #   User.new(password: 'test').password_hash #=> "$2a$12$FktSw7HPYEUYSPBdmmsiXe26II6UV5gvyn2ECwOflTYHP94Hrm2mS"
  def password=(new_password)
    @password = BCrypt::Password.create(new_password)

    self.password_hash = @password
  end
```

In your first test, you're trying to compare a hashed password to an unhashed string.